# Is there a way to dynamically build the x axis variables

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

Set up a date frame

```
 a <- c(5, 10, 15, 20)
 b <- c(50, 100, 150, 200)
 c <- c(150, 200, 250, 300)
 d <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
 df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
 names(df) <- c("XData1", "XData2", "XData3", "YData")
 df
  XData1 XData2 XData3 YData
1      5     50    150     A
2     10    100    200     B
3     15    150    250     C
4     20    200    300     D
```

Using the lattice library, create a barchart

```
barchart(YData ~ XData1, data=df)
```

Create a second, more complicated barchart using

```
barchart(YData ~ XData1+XData2+XData3, data=df, stack=TRUE)
```

Now the question is, how to create the barchart using a function.

Create the first chart by calling a function like this:

```
CreateBarChart(df, c('XData1'), c('YData'))
```

and the second chart by calling a function like this:

```
CreateBarChart(df, c('XData1','XData2','XData3'), c('YData'))
```

What do I do in the function to create the barchart?  That is what I don't understand.  I need to dynamically build the `XData1+XData2+XData3` string in a variable and use it in the barchart.

ORIGINAL QUESTION

I have a set of data that includes a varying number of columns to include in the graph.  The simple case, the command looks like this:

`barchart(my_data[, ycol] ~ my_data[, xcol])`

In the more complicated case, the command looks like this:

`barchart(my_data[, ycol] ~ my_data[, xcol][[1]]+my_data[, xcol][[2]]+my_data[, xcol][[3]])`

The issue is that the number of xcol variables can vary.

I want to build the `my_data[, xcol][[1]]+my_data[, xcol][[2]]+my_data[, xcol][[3]]` part of the command dynamically based on the `length(xcol)`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build up the string and convert into a formula. barchart can then take that and the data:

```
CreateBarChart=function(Data,YVAR,XVAR){
FORMULA = as.formula(paste(YVAR,"~",paste(XVAR,collapse="+")))
barchart(FORMULA,data=Data)
}
```

We test:

```
CreateBarChart(df,'YData','XData1')
```

[image]

```
CreateBarChart(df,'YData',c('XData1','XData2'))
```

[image]